# Does Log4Net have something comparable to Log4J's Markers?

Tags: .net, log4net

Does log4net have something comparable to [log4j's Markers](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Marker.html)?

> Markers are objects that are used to add easily filterable information to log messages.

I've looked through the [log4net API](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/index.html), but the ILog interface doesn't have any methods that accept any extra tokens that could be interpreted as a Marker type of thing.

For example, I only want to log to a single logger:

```
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
logger.Error("This is an error!");
```

However, sometimes I will want these errors to be placed in the EventLog.

Currently I created a second logger with an EventLogAppender referenced. It inherits all the appenders from the root logger too.

That means I need 2 logger references in the class that is going to be logging. 1 for logging to event log, and 1 for logs that I don't want to go to event log:

```
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass)); //root logger
ILog eventLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("EventLogger"); //eventlog logger
logger.Info("Some message that doesn't need to go to the event log.");
eventLogger.Error("Some error that does need to go to the event log.");
```

With markers, I'd be able to do something like

```
logger.Info(EVENT_LOG_MARKER, "This message should go to the event log.");
```

Then a filter would pickup the marker, and activate the appropriate appenders.

I could append a magic string to the beginning of the message, and pick that out with a Filter, but that is hackish at best it would seem.

Short of using magic strings, is there another option in log4net for implementing a Marker type system?

Answer (score 3):

There are no markers in the `ILog` interface of log4net, but you can use [property filters](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter.html) to route your events to the correct logger: just create a single logger in your code and send all events to this logger. In your root configuration set the two appenders you want

```
root
    event log appender
    file appender
```

and then in each appender filter out messages that either have or not the correct property value, e.g.

```
<!-- filter in the event log appender -->
<filter type="log4net.Filter.Property">
    <key value="ToEventLog" />
    <stringToMatch value="true" />
</filter>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

Albeit it is magic strings ported to properties instead of the message, and you need to wrap your logging in some code setting the property: using a IDisposable to wrap the setup and teardown of the property could be a good idea, something like:

```
log.Info("To wherever!!");
using (var SendToEventLogSwitch = new EventLogSwitch)
{
    log.Info("To EventLog!!");
}
```

You could also use an extension method on the ILog to add the marker and use the property mechanism behind the scenes.

```
public static void EventLog(this ILog log, string message)
{
    log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["ToEventLog"] = "true";
    log.Info(message);
    log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["ToEventLog"] = "false";
}
```

Comment: With extension methods, I could create a pseudo Marker extension for the interface. That's a good idea! Thanks for the suggestion.